# Фильтр для select

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Получаю данные с сервера с помощью функции `window.load`:

```
window.load = function (onSuccess, onError) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'json';

    xhr.open('GET', URL);
    console.log(xhr.open('GET', URL));
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        if (xhr.status === SUCCESS) {
            window.data = xhr.response;
            onSuccess(xhr.response.slice(PINS_LIMIT));
        } else {
            onError(ERROR_SERVER);
        }
    });
    xhr.send();
    window.onSuccess = onSuccess(xhr.response.slice(PINS_LIMIT));
};
```

На основе данных, полученных с сервера мне нужно написать фильтр для `select`. Как это можно сделать на ванильном `js`?
Моя неудачная попытка:

```
var housingType = document.getElementById('housing-type');
housingType.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
  if (housingType.value.type === this.value) {
      return window.data.filter(function(it) {
          return it.typeHouse === this.value;
    });
  }
})
```

фильтр по value:

```
<option value="house">Дом</option>
```

json c сервера

```
author: {avatar: ""}
location: {x: 471, y: 545}
offer: {title: "", address: "", price: 30, type: "house", rooms: 1, …}
```

**proto**: Object

Comment: Приведите пример данных и желаемый фильтр.

Comment: фильтр по value :  <option value="house">Дом</option>        Пример json c сервера  {author: {…}, offer: {…}, location: {…}}

Comment: По подробнее `json` и в праку в вопрос. Вопрос можно править.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если представленный JSON является значениями одного дома, то есть JSON для нескольких домой будет иметь вид:

```
data: [
    {
        author: {
            avatar: ""
        },
        location: {x: 471, y: 545},
        offer: {title: "Первый", address: "", price: 30, type: "house", rooms: 1}
    },
    {
        author: {
            avatar: ""
        },
        location: {x: 471, y: 545},
        offer: {title: "Второй", address: "", price: 30, type: "house", rooms: 2}
    },
    {
        author: {
            avatar: ""
        },
        location: {x: 471, y: 545},
        offer: {title: "Третий", address: "", price: 30, type: "notHouse", rooms: 3}
    }
]
```

то, можно сделать так (за место `inputData` подставляете свою переменную с данными соответственно). Данный пример сделан из тех данных которые Вы предоставили:

```js
//Распарсили JSON и получаем объект
var inputData = {data: [
 {
   author: {
     avatar: ""
    },
    location: {x: 471, y: 545},
    offer: {title: "Первый", address: "", price: 30, type: "house", rooms: 1}
  },
  {
   author: {
     avatar: ""
    },
    location: {x: 471, y: 545},
    offer: {title: "Второй", address: "", price: 30, type: "house", rooms: 2}
  },
  {
   author: {
     avatar: ""
    },
    location: {x: 471, y: 545},
    offer: {title: "Третий", address: "", price: 30, type: "notHouse", rooms: 3}
  }
]};

function showData(inputArr) {
 var cont = document.getElementById('output');
  cont.innerHTML = '';
  inputArr.map(function(item) {
   cont.innerHTML += '<div class="item">'+ item.offer.title +'</div>';
  });
}

showData(inputData.data);
var houseType = document.getElementById('housing-type');
houseType.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
 var elem = e.target;
  var newArray = inputData.data.filter(function(item) {
   return elem.value === item.offer.type
  });
  showData(newArray);
});
```

```css
.item {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select id="housing-type">
  <option disabled selected>
    Выберите тип дома
  </option>
  <option value="house">
    Дом
  </option>
  <option value="notHouse">
    Не дом
  </option>
</select>

<div id="output">

</div>
```